# Juju bootstrap not working with vsan

Tags: juju, vmware

Not sure what is going on but when I try to bootstrap juju and my datastore is a vsan storage it will hang up on the deployment. Here is the command I am running

```
juju bootstrap vsphere/Home --bootstrap-constraints "cores=2 mem=4G root-disk=32G" --config primary-network=Production --config datastore=vsanDatastore --debug
```

Everything seems to work until the VM starts up. The VM starts but it does not even leave the bios it states that there is no operating system found. Meaning that however, it cloned the image the data was not there. If I use a non vsan datastore it works perfectly.

Anyone have any ideas what might be up??

Comment: Is there anything in the Juju logs around the same time? https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/troubleshooting-logs

Comment: As the troubleshooting logs are for a running controller I can't even connect to see these logs. In short though juju builds the VM and starts it up the VM never even boots the host operating system. The problem seems to be with how juju copies the VM data.

Comment: on booting it just skips over the cdrom pointing to _ovfenv-juju.*.iso and drops through to the vmware pxe boot.  Upgrading the vmware hardware version to 11, 13, or 14 do not make any difference.

Comment: This problem is a vsan problem.  I can bootstrap to a san volume on vsphere 6.7 and then storage motion it to a vsan volume.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1807957). The workaround is to bootstrap Juju to a SAN-backed volume, then use [vSphere's vMotion](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc/GUID-629454B1-DCB4-4018-BB17-FB053E2473C9.html) feature to migrate the VM(s) to a vSAN-backed volume.

The cause of this issue is complex, but interesting for the technically inclined.

Juju starts with the assumption that your Datacenter does not contain a disk image for a supported operating system (the current Ubuntu Server LTS). So, it streams a .vmdk file extracted from the official Ubuntu archives into the vSphere Datacenter.

This would normally be fine, but Juju wants to apply some advanced customisation to the VMs it is deploying. So rather than using the standard vSphere APIs for importing a VM, Juju uses some lower-level tools. It turns out though that .vmdk files are not compatible with all datastore backends. It looks like those low-level tools skip a conversion step that's performed by the high level tools.